# Dynamic and Clean URL

Tags: php, clean-urls

So I'm build a site that has user profiles. what I want to do is grab from the database the users username and display it in the url, so something like this:

example.com/profile/derrick in stead of showing (example.com/profile.php?id=123)

I always want to do this with the photos that they upload as well. I want to grab the title of the photo and make it the url:

example.com/shots/my-photo-title-here in stead of showing (example.com/shots.php?id=13)

If anyone has a good tutorial out there, or script they wrote themselves I would be very happy to know about it. Thanks!

Comment: Found these 2 tutorials, worth going through. http://forum.codecall.net/topic/74170-clean-urls-with-php/ and http://www.cutcodedown.com/tutorials/friendlyURL/

Answer (score 3):

Use:
`$urlarray = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);`

Example:
Url: www.mysite.com/this/is/it

```
$urlarray[1] will by this
$urlarray[2] will by is
$urlarray[3] will by it
```

There from you can try it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very good tutorial regarding clean urls:

[Clean URls](http://www.desiquintans.com/articles.php?page=cleanurls)

One of the better ones I found that actually worked.  Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice generator for clean URLs: http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/.